# UK Mobile phone and UK landline regex

Tags: regex

I have the following 2 regex for UK mobile phone number and for UK landline numbers respectively-

```
^0(7\\d{9})\$

^0([1-6]\\d{8,10})\
```

I need to combine them into one regex to validate an input field using JavaScript to be any UK mobile or landline. I’ve tried using the | (pipe symbol) for ‘or’, but that’s not working and doesn’t recognise either of them.
Anyone any suggestions as to how best to combine.
Many thanks in advance,

Comment: Please add example phone numbers for those unfamiliar with the types of phone numbers that you're talking about.

Comment: Try `^0([1-6][0-9]{8,10}|7[0-9]{9})$`

Comment: If my answer did not solve your problem please consider updating the question.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to combine the patterns, you may use

```
^0([1-6][0-9]{8,10}|7[0-9]{9})$
```

Note that the common prefix is outside the parentheses, the rest is an alternation group with anchors outside of the group.

[image]

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `0` - a zero
- `([1-6][0-9]{8,10}|7[0-9]{9})` - either of the two alternatives

  - `[1-6][0-9]{8,10}` - a digit from `1` to `6` and then 8 to 10 digits
  - `|` - or
  - `7[0-9]{9}` - `7` and any 9 digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Wow where did you get this regex graph from?

Comment: @KevinH [Here it is](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E0(%5B1-6%5D%5B0-9%5D%7B8%2C10%7D%7C7%5B0-9%5D%7B9%7D)%24).

Comment: Great answer - just one addition - 06 isn't valid, and 08 is :)

Comment: @NickW The question is about joining two regular expressions. Most probably, OP meant to match specific numbers, or already outdated numbers. I tried to answer in a way that everyone can adjust the regex for their needs. Just modify `[1-6]` or `7` to accommodate for your rules, or/and add another alternative by adding a `|` or operator after `[0-9]{9}`.

Comment: Sure, it wasn't intended a criticism of the answer, just thought it made sense to add the comment to the answer that people will use rather than respond to the question itself. Appreciate the answer though - have found it useful